# Replace "per 100,000 people" with a more general term

Tags: terminology, technical, titles

I want to title a graph. If it represented percentages, I could say something like "Percentage of people in full-time employment". If it contained fractions I could write "Fraction of people in full-time employment" etc, etc. But my graph shows the data in terms of the number of people per 100,000. The best I can come up with is "Number of people per 100,000 in full-time employment" but I'd like to include the "per 100,000" part under the graph and have a shorter title. Any suggestions on how best to do this? For example, could I write "Proportion of people in full-time employment"?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your chosen title. It possibly can't get crisper than that.

Comment: Proportion is not appropriate. It is understood as a ratio of two numbers, not as an absolute number. Hence you cannot use it in your context in relation to an absolute number such as 100000 unless you state both numbers you are using to make the ratio: presumably the *number employed* within a *population of 100000*.

Comment: Your Y axis will already say it's per 100,000s.

Comment: I believe you are asking about the graph’s title not the 2 axes’ labels. I don’t think the title should repeat everything that is in the x and y axes’ labels, e.g. *Full Time Employment Totals* might suffice?

Comment: Interestingly, graph axes, when necessary, are labeled with the factor the graph maker **divided by** to get the numbers graphed, e.g., (**per** 100,000), x10^-5 (**negative** powers of 10), whereas instrument dials like pressure gauges and tachometers are labeled with the number you need to **multiply by** to get the value intended from the indicated number, e.g. rpm x100, psi x10.

Comment: If you're looking to abbreviate, you could say "No. Employed Full-Time" and then, "per 100k".

Answer (score 1):

The term **crude rate** is used, but not exclusively for 100,000.

For instance,

> A crude rate is the total number of cases or deaths divided by the total population and multiplied by 100,000 (for cancers by primary site) or by 1 million (for International Classification of Childhood Cancer [ICCC] groupings of childhood cancers).

[CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/cancer/uscs/about/hints.htm#:%7E:text=A%20crude%20rate%20is%20the,%5D%20groupings%20of%20childhood%20cancers)

Implied in the crude rate is that some standard scaling by a constant has been applied to push numbers to a human readable form.

This explanation shows typical values of the scaling constant, at least in the mind of the author.

> A crude rate is defined as the total number of events, or count, divided by the mid-year total population of the selected geography and multiplied by a constant, which is a multiple of 10. Typical constants used for public health rates include 100, 1,000, 10,000, or 100,000.

[MOPHIMS](https://health.mo.gov/data/documentation/crude-aarate.php#:%7E:text=A%20crude%20rate%20is%20defined,1%2C000%2C%2010%2C000%2C%20or%20100%2C000)

By using **crude rate** in your title, you can push the scaling factor to elsewhere in the graph, such as the axis label. The title could be "crude rate of full-time employment", or simply (and in my experience much more commonly) "full-time employment rate", with the crude rate given on the appropriate axis.